# How to implement EditText and Save Edited Text with a single button?

Tags: android, buttonclick

**Implemeted onclick Listener on a button**

```
private void clickListener(){

    edit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Edit is tapped",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

*enabled to edit the text*

```
            tv_location.setFocusable(true);
            tv_location.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);

            sample.setFocusable(true);
            sample.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);

            edit.setPressed(false);

            edit.setText("Save");
```

*Storing changed values and displaying in edit text*

```
                final String location_txt = tv_location.getText().toString();
                tv_location.setText(location_txt);
                final String sample_text = sample.getText().toString();
                sample.setText(sample_text);
```

*disabled edit text*

```
                tv_location.setFocusable(false);
                tv_location.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);

                sample.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
                sample.setFocusable(false);

                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Details have been saved",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        }
    });
}
```

Comment: i don't understand

Comment: please elaborate your question

Comment: I have a single button which should work like when it is tapped. it enable the edit text field which allows user to edit the text and when the text is changed the user should be able to save the changed text, using this button only.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private boolean isEditTextEnabled;

button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (isEditTextEnabled) {
                    String text = editText.getText().toString();
                   //save your text
                } else {
                    editText.setEnabled(true);
                    isEditTextEnabled = true;
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Make each of tour code snippets a private method:

```
private void enable() {
    tv_location.setFocusable(true);
    tv_location.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    sample.setFocusable(true);
    sample.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    edit.setPressed(false);
    edit.setText("Save");
}

private void disable() {
    tv_location.setFocusable(false);
    tv_location.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
    sample.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
    sample.setFocusable(false);
}

private void store() {
    final String location_txt = tv_location.getText().toString();
    tv_location.setText(location_txt);
    final String sample_text = sample.getText().toString();
    sample.setText(sample_text);
}
```

and this is your listener:

```
    edit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (sample.isEnabled()) {
                if (!sample.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
                    store();
                    disable();
                }
            } else {
                enable();
            }
        }
    });
```